# C# convert string to double in locale

Tags: c#, string-conversion

In my locale the decimal separator is a ','.

However I would still like to write a C# application which works with numbers that use the '.' as decimal separator.

```
        string b = "0,5";
        double db = double.Parse(b); // gives 0.5

        string a = "0.5";
        double da = double.Parse(a); // gives 5, however i would like to get 0.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/c-how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo
Look here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the culture as the second argument to [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx), e.g.

```
double da = double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Pretty much all of the formatting/parsing methods have overloads taking an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx), and the most commonly-specified implementation of `IFormatProvider` is [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).

Comment: That only works if the value within string was stored using invariant culture. If it wasn't, 0.5 will be parsed as 0.5, while 0,5 will be parsed as 5... It seems that there's no way to get the ultimate solution.

Comment: @dzendras: The question states a requirement of "write a C# application which works with numbers that use the '.' as decimal separator" - the answer is meant to meet that requirement.