# Convert.ToDouble("1.3") returns 13

Tags: c#, .net, casting, transformation

What's going on here?

```
Convert.ToDouble("1.3")
```

I have a string with the value "1.3". When I convert to double, it returns 13. I want to return 1.3.

Comment: Just a guess, is your regional format something like `$1.000.000,00`

Comment: What happens if you use the `Convert.ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)` overload instead?

Comment: @Seva In that case, you're formatting numbers using your local culture settings.  Use the overload I suggested (and in the answer below), and it'll work as you expect.

Comment: have you done _any_ research before asking this?

Comment: @Selman22, do you earn reputation by only commenting these stuff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# convert string to double in locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426978/c-sharp-convert-string-to-double-in-locale) **and** [How do I parse a string with a decimal point to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double) **and** [how to convert string to double with proper cultureinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo)

Comment: @Selman22 Locale-dependent questions are the sort of thing that most people have to encounter once as a "problem" before they realise what the question really is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It probably has to do with your current culture, it uses another decimal separator symbol than `.`. You can do this instead:

```
double.Parse("1.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was tricky. I will mark as answer when possible.