# InvalidCastException when importing MySQL double to C#

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, casting

I have a C# program which uses `MySqlDataReader` to connect to a MySQL DB. At one point it imports a DB field of datatype `double`, into a C# variable also of type `double`:

```
MyDBTable table = new MyDBTable();
table.myDouble = row.GetValueOrDefault<double>("double_field");
```

But this results in the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Why am I getting this error? I thought that the MySQL `double` type corresponds to the C# `double` type.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code to see which object is stored inside the column `"double_field"`? Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138013/c-problems-with-getting-double-values-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your double_field is nullable and making double value from null is not supported. try to do

```
object o = row.GetValueOrDefault<object>("double_field");
```

and look what o object will contain.