# different results on emulator and windows phone device c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So i am working on an application that does some calculations. It reads some numbers from a txt, it converts them to double and after it multiplies them it gives the result.

Lets say the txt has the numbers 10.5 and 2

```
string string1 = "10.5", string2 = "2";
double double1 = Convert.ToDouble(string1), double2=Convert.ToDouble(string2);
double double3=double1*double2;
textbox.text= double3.ToString();
```

The result I always get on emulator is 21 while on my device i get 210. I tried reinstalling the app from the phone, restarting the phone and the pc and i tried this over 10 times. I still get different results on my phone. What should i do?

PS: i tried double.parse but still the same

Comment: Sounds like a culture problem? Could it be reading the `.` as a thousands separator and ignoring it?

Comment: so you are suggesting to add "," instead of "." ?

Comment: but on emulator it works just fine. why is this?

Comment: @user1924391 The phone and the emulator may be working under different locales.  One interprets '.' as a decimal point, the other interprets  its as a number separator.

Comment: Because the emulator is running the same locale as your computer; the phone may not. Try a `Double.Parse` and specify the culture and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis that the phone and emulator are working under different locales, then this SO question answers what is really being asked [how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo)

Of course you are now going to have to match your text file to the corrected locale.

Also see [what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean)

Comment: thanks. i will check it out. the txt uses "." as a decimal point and i want the phone no matter what locale its working under to use it as a decimal point too.

Comment: i tried the following and it worked on both phone and emulator. thank you all guys! 

double.Parse(Settings.appSettings[tcholcLog].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);