# Convert String to Double, Explicitly Using Period as Decimal Point

Tags: c#, iformatprovider

One of my software's functions is to convert numeric strings into `double` datatype. I want to  explicitly indicate the use of period (.) as a decimal point. Thus, no matter the language settings of the user's system, it will correctly read a period-separated decimal. I believe the solution is to use the `IFormatProvider` argument in the `Convert.ToDouble()` function. I am unsure how to do this.

Example:
String: "3.14"
Double: 3.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`  while parsing.

```
double d = double.Parse("3.14", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with
>   the English language but not with any country/region.

Answer (score 1):

```
double.Parse(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Edit: or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo)