# Decimal Point ignored in Convert.ToDouble

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double

In C# visual studio not taking decimal points in double after read and converted into double using

```
Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

command... For example if `12.25` is typed it saves the value as `1225`. Can I get any help?
This is the Code i'm using.

```
double number;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number with a two decimal places!");
number = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(number):
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you show the code because what you describe should be working correctly.

Comment: You might have the wrong culture, it might be looking for `,` instead of `.` as a seperator. (Also please change your title to a more descriptive one)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've shown the code now..!

Comment: And sorry for weak phrased question as i'm new to this..!

Comment: @AbdulRaheem have you tried converting it to int and then converting the int to a double?

Comment: I just tested it [here](https://ideone.com/xRizms) and if it is a Culture issue, an exception is thrown. But it doesn't look like you are getting an exception, are you? (Also, the 3rd line of code has a capital 'N'. Is that a typo?)

Comment: that was a typo i've corrected it and i thought if i convert the input into int first it would omit the decimal places and round off the value so i was tried directly converting input string to double.P.SI wrote the code on a differnet computer it worked but when i opened the same code on my laptop it wasn't working so i'm thinking probably there's something fishy about culture on my laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert string to double with proper cultureinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your current code should be working as expected and if it isn't, it's likely the result of cultural issues that expect your double string to be in a different format (i.e. `12,25` instead of `12.25`).

**Applying the Current Culture When Parsing**

You can handle this issue by applying the current culture when parsing your value within the [`Convert.ToDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx) method through the `System.Globalization` namespace:

```
// This would use the current culture to handle reading your value
double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Handling Various Cultures (i.e. periods or commas)**

If you wanted to expect to handle either periods or commas, you could potentially perform a replacement the in the same manner :

```
// Get the number separator for this culture and replace any others with it
var separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
// Replace any periods or commas with the current culture separator and parse
var input = Double.Parse(Regex.Replace(Console.ReadLine(),"[.,]",separator));
```

You can [see a working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i4MZBz).

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was helpfull..!

Answer (score 6):

When you local culture doesn't use `.` as a decimal delimiter it won't work.
If you want to enter doubles with a `.` decimal separator, you need to specify a culture that does use it.

```
Convert.ToDouble(yourString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you want to **output** it in the same format, use the same `CultureInfo` again:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), culture);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(culture, "{0}", input));
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a **globalization issue** as some cultures use , instead of . to separate decimal places. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
double inputInDouble = Convert.ToDouble(userInput,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```