# C#: Input string was not in a correct format but everything should work

Tags: c#

The program should read the number from [**this file**](https://github.com/denisnumb/Keyboardpp/blob/main/last_version) and convert it to `double`.

Everything works fine everywhere except for one device.  On my friend's laptop, the code throws an `Input string was not in a correct format` exception.

At the same time, before converting, I specifically output a string that should be converted to `double` and this string corresponds to the format.

What could be the problem?

**Code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double newVersion = 0;
            try
            {
                string data = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisnumb/Keyboardpp/main/last_version");
                data = data.Replace(".", ",");
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                newVersion = Convert.ToDouble(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{newVersion}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output on my device:**

```cs
0,92

0,92
```

**Output on a friend's device:**

```cs
0,92

Input string was not in a correct format
0
```

Comment: Are you assuming that on your friend device the comma is the separator for doubles?

Comment: If your friend put 0.92 it will work, this is related to localisation (culture) settings

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be converting version numbers to, well, numbers. What if the version changes to `1.0-beta` for example?

Comment: His system culture maybe different.

Comment: Different culture of computers. One of you has comma and the dot seperated doubles. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo

Comment: A others pointed out this is related to the decimal separtor settend in the laptop localisations

Comment: Don't use `Convert.ToDouble` and don't replace commas with periods (or vice versa), use `Double.TryParse` and pass the appropriate `NumberStyles` and `CultureInfo`. ...actually don't even do that, because as others have pointed out version numbers aren't doubles. Keep it strings, or if you really must use `String.Split` with integers, or if you *really* must at least use `Decimal` (and note that [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version) is a thing).

Comment: @DavidG my code only reads the numeric version.  The structure is such that if the version is less than 0, then the code automatically adds the inscription `Beta` to it, if not, then it remains just a number

Comment: I'd recommand using [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tryparse?view=net-6.0) class.

Comment: You probably want that version 0.9 is less than 0.15, or? When parsed as double, it will be greater, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your code and have the following input:

- Use HttpClient instead of WebClient.

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var data = await client.GetStringAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisnumb/Keyboardpp/main/last_version");
```

- Use Tryparse instead of a convert, in this case, you can choose the type, if you really need it in double or as mentioned in the comment as Version type.

```cs
NumberFormatInfo formatWithComma = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatWithComma.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
double.TryParse(data, NumberStyles.Any, formatWithComma, out newVersion);
```

Or

```cs
//newVersion type should be Version and not double
Version.TryParse(data, out newVersion);
```

If you wrap it up, here is my suggestion, with double.TryParse

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    double newVersion = 0;
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var data = await client.GetStringAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisnumb/Keyboardpp/main/last_version");

        NumberFormatInfo formatWithComma = new NumberFormatInfo();
        formatWithComma.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        var parsed = double.TryParse(data, NumberStyles.Any, formatWithComma, out newVersion);

        if (parsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newVersion);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"some thing went wrong {data}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{newVersion}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or with Version.TryParse

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Version newVersion = null;
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var data = await client.GetStringAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denisnumb/Keyboardpp/main/last_version");

        var parsed = Version.TryParse(data, out newVersion);

        if (parsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newVersion);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"some thing went wrong {data}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{newVersion}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```